# Redux: Updating the store with simultaneous dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying a simple example of rendering 2 components via dispatching an action on `componentWillMount()` which updates the store.

Initial State:

```
export default {
  dashboards: [],
  dashboardContent: []
};
```

2 Reducers:

```
export default function dashboardContentReducer(state = initialState.dashboardContent, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
      return action.dashboardContent;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and

```
export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState.dashboards, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
      return action.dashboards;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here's where things get a little weird.

I am able to dispatch the action to call these reducers, but only 1 of them will function to update the `redux store`. I do so as follows:

```
class NavigationBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(dashboardActions.loadDashboards());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="rc-navigationBar">
        <h1>Navigation!</h1>
          {this.props.dashboards.map((dashboard, index) => {
            return <h1 key={index}>{dashboard.title}</h1>
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and for the other:

```
class ContentPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(dashboardContentActions.loadDashboardContent(extractIdFromRoute()));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Content!</h1>
          {this.props.dashboardContent.map((content, index) => {
            return <h1 key={index}>{content.application}</h1>;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I simultaneously try to modify the store, I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'dashboards.1.filter.Pivot.ancestorOrigins'. This may cause incorrect behavior.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning it in a wrong way. It should be like this -

```
export default function dashboardContentReducer(state = default, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, { dashboardContent:action.dashboardContent });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Every time you will have to return new Object from reducer. In that way it will maintain mutability of state.

Comment: Hmm... This seemed to have turned my initial state of an array into an object. How do I keep it an array?

Comment: your action.dashboardContent should be an array. Check out my updated solution.

Comment: This seems to have set it!

Comment: your initial state should be an Object. If you want to return the default value as an array do it like `return state.dashboardContent`. Instead of returning state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133610/discussion-between-iggy2012-and-rohan-veer).